# New-ExoPSSession: Index was out of range

Tags: powershell, powershell-4.0, microsoft365, office365-exchange

Im developing a script that connects to Exchange Online Microsoft 365, but when the script executes the cmdlet "Connect-ExchangeOnline", it ends with errors.

The specific instruction is:

```
Connect-ExchangeOnline -Organization $myTenant -AppId $AppId -Certificate $myCert
```

The variables in the parameters are correct, the error says:

**New-ExoPSSession: Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection. Parameter name: index**

I can load the module succesfully. The script connects to Exchange Online trough a cert installed in my machine, my script can read it without issues.

I'm running this script in Powershell V4 and .Net Framework 4.7.1. If i execute the same script in another machine with PowerShell V5.1 I can connect to Microsoft 365 Exchange Online succesfully. I tried with a lower version (ExchangeOnlineManagement 1.0.1) but this version hasn't got those parameters (Organization, AppId, etc...), I'm now using 2.0.3 version. I not sure if you can upgrade Powershell to 5.1.

Does anyone know why i can't connect to Exchange Online?

Comment: Verify parameters used for the `New-ExoPSSession` cmdlet. If you're using an array (exemple $somevalues[3] and $somevalues has a length of 2, then 3 is out of range. This is an example of such error happening.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. New-ExoPSSession is a internal cmdlet (it inside Connect-ExchangeOnline), i don't call this method. All variables are strings, not arrays, except $MyCert that is Certificate type.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EXO V2 is [only supported on PowerShell 5.1 and later](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/exchange/exchange-online-powershell-v2?view=exchange-ps#windows). If you want to use PowerShell 4.0 [you will have to use EXO V1](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/exchange/v1-module-mfa-connect-to-exo-powershell?view=exchange-ps#what-do-you-need-to-know-before-you-begin).

I'm not familiar enough with the EXO module to how or whether you can use EXO V1 in your current environment. If V2 is required for modern Exchange Online management then you will need to upgrade your nodes to use WMF 5.1 or install PowerShell Core (7+) and use EXO V2 from there.

PowerShell Core installs in parallel to Windows PowerShell so there is less of a risk of impacting other code which requires PowerShell 4.0 if you go this route.

Comment: I see in your links the minimum version from Powershell. I don't know why in Powershell gallery indicates that the minor version is "PowerShell 3" for ExchangeOnlineManagement 2.0.3.  I think i'll move the scripts to another machine.

Answer (score 3):

I've been struggling with this issue, and I finally found a solution.
Turns out running `Import-Module ExchangeOnlineManagement` before `Connect-ExchangeOnline` causes this error.
Removing `Import-Module ExchangeOnlineManagement` was enough to allow `Connect-ExchangeOnline` to connect without the New-ExoPSSession: Index was out of range error

Answer (score 0):

I am using Windows PowerShell 5.1 and this seems to be an issue that's introduced in ExchangeOnlineManagement version 2.0.4.

Downgrading to 2.0.3 worked for me.

Answer (score -1):

PowerShell needs to be started in elevated mode. However, my error was caused by RunAs with a domain admin account. Using RunAs with a local admin account works. YMMV.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).